# set a layer-list item from SVG

Tags: android, svg, layer-list

I have an interesting question.

```
<layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <size android:width="@dimen/cb_shape_size" android:height="@dimen/cb_shape_size"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/cb_unchecked_solid"/>
                <stroke android:width="@dimen/cb_shape_stroke"
                        android:color="@color/cb_checked_stroke"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_cb_gps_off"
              android:gravity="center"/>
    </layer-list>
```

The **main_cb_gps_off** is a svg file.
The preview likes this in Android Studio:

[image]

But the view likes this when I run the project in my phone(Android4.4.2):

[image]

And when I run the project in the phone of Android6.0, the view is as same as the preview of Android Studio.
Then at the same time, I found that:

```
<layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/main_cb_gps_off"
                  android:gravity="center"/>
        </layer-list>
```

This code runs in Android4.4.2, the size of svg file is normal.
So I don't know why the siez of svg file becomes larger when the "layer-list" has two item. I want to know. Any solution?

Comment: `The main_cb_gps_off is a svg file`, Instead, I think that the main_cb_gps_off is a VectorDrawable. They are not interchangeable. VectorDrawables use a **limited subset** of the SVG structure. And the underlying xml is different.

Comment: have any solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `drawable` in `layer-list`, it will be scaled to fit the view it's in.

From the documentation:

> All drawable items are scaled to fit the size of the containing View,
>   by default. Thus, placing your images in a layer list at different
>   positions might increase the size of the View and some images scale as
>   appropriate.

To avoid scaling, you have to use a `bitmap`:

> To avoid scaling items in the list, use a `bitmap` element inside the
>   `item` element to specify the drawable and define the gravity to
>   something that does not scale, such as "center".

From: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList

Comment: You can't use SVG with bitmap tag, you will get a "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <bitmap> requires a valid 'src' attribute" error

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size inside your SVG xml file, if you declare it's size to `100dp` for width and height, the layer list will be use that values to draw your icon.

If you need to increase or decrease the size, do it inside your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I used two separate ImageView in `<FrameLayout>` with `android:layout_gravity="center"`